# <clip-path> not rendering in VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

It's as simple as it sounds - entering a  into a VectorDrawable has no effect.
Snippet:

```
    <group android:name="32group">
        <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="..." />
        <clip-path android:pathData="..." />
    </group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to swap the clip path to be the first element in the group. I was not able to find any documentation telling this, it was just an educated guess.

Corrected snippet:

```
    <group android:name="32group">
        <clip-path android:pathData="..." />
        <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="..." />
    </group>
```

Comment: How to draw border around the <clip-path> ?  stroke-color and stroke-width is not working ?

Comment: Make a new path with the same pathData as the cliip-path

Comment: Tried it. not working. Can you share the code please ?

Comment: No. Ask a new question.